# why const int can be changed using scanf?

Tags: c, constants

I cant understand why this is working.

```
#include<stdio.h>

void main(){
  const int x = 100;
  printf("x = %d \n",x);
  scanf("%d",&x); //working fine
  printf("x = %d \n",x); //prints the new value
}
```

Answer (score 4):

It's not working fine, modifying const variables are undefined behavior. Anything could happen.

Using `-Wall` with GCC, you will see:

> warning: writing into constant object (arg 2)

Answer (score 2):

It's UB generally. 
May be you see result of a casting in your case.
For example:

```
void main(void)
{
    int const x = 100;
    int *x2 = &x;
    *x2 = 2; 
}
```

is working on my machine, but

```
void main(void)
{
    int const x = 100;
    x = 2; 
}
```

isn't (compilation error). 
Anyway, it is better not to change the const variables.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to change it but the behavior is undefined, as its mentioned in the standard!

Its in c11 under 6.7.3

> If an attempt is made to modify an object defined with a const-qualified type through use of an lvalue with non-const-qualified type, the behavior is undefined. If an attempt is made to refer to an object defined with a volatile-qualified type through use of an lvalue with non-volatile-qualified type, the behavior is undefined.